# Why I need to define Dispose in my base class although its abstract?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I writing application that takes `Wireshark` File (Pcap, Snopp, Pcapng...) open this file and read all the `Packets`.

So i create this `abstract class` that every class that inherit from this class will need to implement the obvious methods in order to have that  ability to open specific format:

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile
{
    protected string _fileName;
    protected int _packets;
    protected string _duration;
    public abstract void ReadFileDetails();
}
```

And all the sub classes:

```
public class Libpcap : WiresharkFile, IDisposable, IEnumerable<WiresharkFilePacket>
{
    ....
}
```

Now when loop over specific format and read packets:

```
using (wiresharkFile = new Libpcap(file))
{

}
```

i have this compilation error:

```
type used in a using statement must be implicitly convertible to 'System.IDisposable'
```

So my question is why i need to implement `IDisposable` in my base class if i cannot create object from this type and what should i write inside this `Dispose` on my base class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `using`-statement tries to call `IDisposable.Dispose` on the instance that you passed to it. This instance is of type `WiresharkFile`. When translated the code looks somehow like this:

```
WiresharkFile wiresharkFile = new Libpcap(file);

try
{
    // ...
}
finally
{
    wiresharkFile.Dispose();
}
```

However `WiresharkFile` does not support the `IDisposable` inteface and therefor `Dispose()` is not defined. Either you simply add `IDisposable` to your abstract base class like this:

```
public abstract class WiresharkFile : IDisposable
{
}
```

where there is no need to *implement* `Dispose` (you have to implement it in `Libpcap`), or you create an instance of `Libpcap` and pass it to the `using`-Statement like this:

```
using(Libpcap wiresharkFile = new Libpcap(file))
{
    // ...
}
```